# Command-line tool 'jar' is not reading directories

Tags: java, jar

I'm running [`jar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html) in order to create a JAR file with the command:

```
jar cmf manifest.txt generatedParser generator gui resource
```

`generatedParser`, `generator`, `gui`, and `resource` are directories, but `jar` doesn't read them, complaining that:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: generatedParser (Is a directory)

But I was under the impression that `jar` would recursively read directories and according to the example in *[Creating a JAR File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)*, the directories audio and images were read just fine. So why doesn't it work, what am I missing? I want to generate a JAR application that contains the packages `generatedParser`, `generator`, `gui` and `resource`. They are normal uncompressed directories that contain class files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `f` flag indicates the presence of the jar file name following the manifest file name on the command line. The correct command line would be

```
jar cmf manifest.txt myJarName.jar generatedParser generator gui resource
```

The error message is the result of `jar` trying to use the directory `generatedParser` as the jar file -- it doesn't work out very well, as you can see.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I new I was stupid somehow and that I just couldn't see it.